# Convergence line for oscillating trend

Tags: predictive-modeling, simulation

I am working with an algorithm studying the response of a system to an external factor (Phenomenon A). The system can either respond perfectly, or can be completely disrupted.

I am plotting the system's response in the following graph, which shows kind of an `oscillating trend`. High `y` values imply poor responses (upper limit: `100`, `total collapse`), whereas low `y` values mean very good responses (lower limit: `0`, `no influence` whatsoever).

I am running this experiment based on an arbitrary number of simulations - in this case, 1000.

**My question:** is there a metric which can help me identify the most appropriate number of simulations? I was thinking of something which could associate an optimal number of runs with a reduction in oscillation (`convergence`). What metric/formula could be useful here?

[image]